# How can i provide discount coupon for each item in shopping cart of kentico ecommerce?

Tags: kentico

[image]

How can i provide discount coupon for each item in shopping cart of kentico ecommerce?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Not saying this will add any features but you need to apply the latest hotfix. You're on a vanilla version of Kentico and it's not a good idea to be on a vanilla version of any software.

Answer (score 0):

It's not out-of-the-box functionality, because you can apply only 1 coupon code to order,  but you can write a custom code for it. In Kentico you can override some methods from data providers (Example for [Shipping option InfoProvider](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/custom-development/customizing-providers/custom-info-provider-example), so you can create a similar class for ShoppingCartInfoProvider or another

Comment: I know i can provide only 1 coupon code, but is there any way that enable me to apply coupon code to individual item in cart as i have given in screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can have global discounts or discounts for specific products. Go to  E-commecrce\Product coupons. You can define percentage or fixed amount. 
Come up with a coupon code. When a user enters this code in the shopping cart - discount automatically applies
[more info here](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/e-commerce-features/configuring-and-managing-your-store/discounts/working-with-discount-coupons/working-with-coupons-for-order-discounts-and-free-shipping-offers)